# html5 canvas stroke as clear line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i currently have the following:

```
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(459,258);
  ctx.rotate(sec * Math.PI/36);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(135,0);
  ctx.lineTo(210,0);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255)';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
```

drawing a circle of lines (stroke). I want to convert it into a `clearRect` so that instead of drawing this circle of lines, i want it to erase a circle in the same shape... how can i do this?

i tried doing this but it did not work:

```
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(459,258);
  ctx.rotate(sec * Math.PI/36);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(135,0);
  ctx.lineTo(210,0);

  ctx.clear();
  ctx.restore();
```

thanks.

Comment: Add ``ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255)'; ctx.stroke();`` and remove ``ctx.clear()`` in your second exmaple might do? basically, draw white lines over your original ones.

Comment: no, it paints a black line going in a circle (without trail)

Comment: why black line? remove the ``ctx.clear`` and add ``ctx.stroke()`` also.

Comment: Have you tried calling clear rect? Rotate to the correct position, and clear a rectangle at at the position you want, for the length you require at a width of 10.

Comment: yay, the clearRect works!